# scaffold generation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here's an excerpt from the Ruby On rails The pragmatic Programmers:

The following command doesn't work on the new Rails, in the script folder I only have the file Rail.

```
ruby script/generate scaffold Product Admin (Product: Model and Admin: Controller)
```

The closest I can get to this instruction is using the following:

```
rail generate scaffold Product Admin:controller
```

but what I get is Product being the controller and Admin isn't anything.

How can I generate scaffold Product Admin, Product being the model and Admin being the controller with the new Rails?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "Admin being the controller"? Rails' resources are following a convention by which the Model and the controller are named according to the resource they're representing. E.g. Model: Product, Controller: ProductsController

Comment: I want to rename ProductsController to admin, should I do it manually? Or is there a command to insure that in one shot?

Comment: Have you considered namespacing? ie. `Admin::Products` controller instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of the book do you have? It sounds like you have the 3rd Edition (Rails 2.x) and that you're using Rails 3 on your machine, which would explain the `script/generate` vs. `rails generate scaffold` inconsistencies.

Comment: I just bought the newest beta version, all my questions got answered. The whole thing changed. They are now using rails generate scaffold product title:string price:decimal etc....

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Rails 3 changed a fair bit, and older documentation/books are going to make things pretty confusing. As an added tip, you can type 'rails g' instead of 'rails generate' at the start of a command as a shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

```
rails generate controller Admin
rails generate model Product
```

?

Comment: No it doesn't work because scaffold automatically links controllers and models to database schemas. It should be something else.

Comment: I think the controller and model should be sharing the same name if they relate to the same database schema, in which case rails generate scaffold Product should work. If you want to change the URL of the controller to be admin, you can do that in your routes file.

Comment: It could work that way, but I think it's neater if I could find this magic command.

Comment: I don't think this magic command exists, because it's not the way Rails (or any other framework) does things.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use scaffolding for this, I'd suggest to rename your controller (file + class name). But consider if e.g. an admin **namespace** might not do what you want.

Your structure will become somewhat harder to understand, if your controller is called `admin controller` and the model `product`, since you'd have to access the resource like this

```
/admin/     # -> returns all products
/admin/new  # -> form for new product
/admin/23   # -> product with id 23
```

See what I mean?

Comment: Yeah I do, it's weird that the book insists on naming the controller admin....maybe they're too lazy to recreate another controller and instead decided to modify slightly the rails generated controller. Which isn't such a bad idea now that I think of it. :)

Comment: I don't have access to the book but could it be, that the product's controller only inherits from an admin controller rather than the application controller?

Answer (score 0):

There are definetly some troubles with admin scaffold generating in Rails. The point of the quesiton is that default rails scaffold generator creates namespaced resources, including namespaced model and that is not very useful, cause models are typically common for admin area and public area.

I also faced this problem and found no standard solution for that.

So, I created [rails-admin-scaffold gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/rails-admin-scaffold) (for now it's Rails 4 only) which automates this process and wrote [an article](http://dhampik.com/blog/rails-admin-scaffold) with more detailed explanation. Though my answer is little outdated, it might help for other people to find suitable solution.